# jQuery Validate doesn't work with an AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Before I even write my problem I want to state that I have read numerous StackOverflow posts about this and I still am running into the same problem. Basically no matter how many ways I alter my code my form still submits without first validating to see if each area is filled. This is my code.

```
 <form id="contact" method="post" action="E-mail-form.php" name="EmailFromMyWebsite">

                <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Your Name" title=" (Your name is required)"> <br />

                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Name@email.com" title=" (Your email is required)"> <br />

                <label for="message">Message/Comment</label> <br>
                <textarea name="message" class="required" placeholder="Leave a brief message" title=" (Please leave me a brief message)"></textarea> <br />

                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </form>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {required: true},
        email: {required: true},
        message: {required: true}
    },
    submitHandler: $(function(form){

        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            var formData = $('#contact').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:formData,
                url:"E-mail-form.php",
                done: function(data){
                    $('#contact').html('<p>Your message has been sent. I will reply to you shortly.</p>');
                },
                fail: function(data) {
                    $('#contact').html('<p>Sorry there was a problem your message was NOT sent.</p>');
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    })
});
});
```

Now I think the first thing someone is going to notice is that I have a function on submit, but I've tried removing that and my form simply won't submit even with the submitHandler. I think that's where the problem is occurring because when I look at other forums with this problem I don't understand what is causing the form to actually submit without that. Any help or explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Where is the markup for the form?

Comment: Sorry about that just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> "Now I think the first thing someone is going to notice is that I have
>   a function on submit, but I've tried removing that and my form simply
>   won't submit even with the submitHandler. I think that's where the
>   problem is occurring because when I look at other forums with this
>   problem I don't understand what is causing the form to actually submit
>   without that. Any help or explanation would be very helpful."

You need to more carefully look at the syntax of those working examples instead of inserting random event handlers.  Putting a `click` handler inside of the `submitHandler` which is only fired *after* the button is clicked makes absolutely no sense.

The form submits without the `click` handler because the jQuery Validate plugin already has one built in.  Even if you didn't use the `submitHandler` callback option, the plugin would automatically capture the `click` event of the button (*as long as it's a `type="submit"`*) and handle it appropriately.  However, in this case, you'll still *need* to define the `submitHandler` callback because it's where your `.ajax()` belongs.

So remove the `click` handler.

Also, your code has syntax errors:

```
submitHandler: $(function(form){
  // your ajax           
})
```

You do not put `$()` around your callback function.

It's simply this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // your ajax
}
```

or with your code...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    var formData = $(form).serialize();  // <- use the "form" argument here
    $.ajax({
       ....
    });
    return false;
}
```

And finally, your button needs to have `type="submit"` in order for the plugin to capture it.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/x4h8L/

Comment: I appreciate your input and thank you for helping me but your script does not work on my site. It appears to not be firing, this is the problem I have had the entire time. When I click submit nothing happens and when I look at your script I don't understand how the SubmitHandler works because it's not attached to any event. That's why  initially I added $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            var formData = $('#contact').serialize();

Comment: @London804, see my edited answer updated with your markup.  Your button wasn't being captured by the plugin because it wasn't a `type="submit"`.  (_why it's important to include your HTML in the OP_.)  Even if I hadn't seen your markup and given the solution, simply compare my working jsFiddle to your site's code to find the problem.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it now validates but does nothing on submit. But I noticed something shouldn't var forData =$('#contact') and not 'form' since contact is the title of the form and that's what I want to serialize?

Comment: Apologizes apparently it is working but I'm not getting the  done: function(data){
                    $('#contact').html('<p>Your message has been sent. I will reply to you shortly.</p>');   To show up on my screen.
                }

Comment: @London804, in this case the function's argument, `form`, represents your `#contact` so `$(form).serialize()` is the same.

Comment: @London804, at least you've gotten your validation working.  Now it seems your new problem is with the `.ajax()`.   Shouldn't `done` be `success` or `complete`?  See the jQuery `.ajax()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I changed 'done' to 'success'.Initially that's what I had and then I changed it to done because I thought that was the newer way of doing it. I guess there is a difference. I appreciate your help and patience.